# Presenting Markers on Map from XML file using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a project going where I am presenting specific markers stored in a MySQL database presented in XML form via a PHP script.

I have set up the XML file, however for some reason the markers are not being pulled through correctly per the following code. I have had an in-depth look at this, even going back to the Google Maps API instructional documentation and can't seem to see anything that is off and would appreciate another set of eyes. The below are the specific scripts for pulling the marker locations form the database, presenting them on the map and then resizing the map depending on the size of the window.

I think this is a valid question, considering it seems like I'm doing something basic/common wrong and clearly missing it because I've been staring at the damn thing forever.

```
<body>

<!--CONTENT DIV--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<div id="over_map">
    <!-- lefft Side bar-->
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/"><img src="beef.png" height="50" width="50"></a>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/"><img src="bread.png" height="50" width="50"></a>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/"><img src="chicken.png" height="50" width="50"></a>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/"><img src="corn.png" height="50" width="50"></a>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/"><img src="milk.png" height="50" width="50"></a>

    <!-- side retailer html table -->
    <div>
        <table align="right">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" height='50' width='120'><img src='loblaws_round.png' height=29px valign="middle"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" height='50' width='120'><img src='nofrills_logos.png' height=29px valign="middle"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" height='50' width='120'><img src='shoppers_round.png' height=29px valign="middle"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" height='50' width='120'><img src='wholefoods_round.png' height=29px valign="middle"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <!-- Rightt Side bar-->
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">Clients</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Use any element to open the sidenav -->
    <div id="menu" onclick="openNav()"><img src="menubutton3.png" height="20" width="25"></div>

</div>


<!--MAP DIV--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div id="map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px */
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "135px";
    }

    /* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }

    //MAP MARKERS------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

//defining custom label

var customLabel = {
        Loblaws: {
            label: 'L'
        },
    };

//Map

function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.6532, -79.3832),
            zoom: 13,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            rotateControl: false,
            fullscreenControl: false,
            draggable: true,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,

        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                new XMLHttpRequest;

            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                    request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                    callback(request, request.status);
                }
            };

            request.open('GET', url, true);
            request.send(null);
        }


//Pulling info from php file 

            downloadUrl('http://www.shrewdily.com/markers.php', function(data) {
                var xml = data.responseXML;
                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
                Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
                    var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
                    var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
                    var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
                    var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                        parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                        parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

                    var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
                    var strong = document.createElement('strong');
                    strong.textContent = name
                    infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
                    infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

                    var text = document.createElement('text');
                    text.textContent = address
                    infowincontent.appendChild(text);
                    var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: point,
                        label: icon.label
                    });
                    marker.addListener('click', function() {
                        infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                });
            });

//Resize based on window size

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
                var center = map.getCenter();
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                map.setCenter(center);
            });
        }

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {

    }

</script>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: There is no map in the posted code.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: If I fix the missing stuff that is necessary for a map, I get a javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: customLabel is not defined` on this line`var icon = customLabel[type] || {};`, if I fix that, I get markers.

Comment: @geocodezip - see above for the rest of my code displaying the map as edited

Comment: @geocodezip corrected, left customLabel

Comment: Do you get any errors in the javascript console?  The code as posted (at least w/o the custom icons) "works" for me.

Comment: Nope, no errors at all, looked at this thoroughly and for whatever reason those markers are simply not appearing? Triple checked, there is no syntax error from what I can see, nor any error in the code  which is why I find it weird?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  Is the XML being read correctly (is it served with the correct MIME type)?  What is the URL of the map?  Is it on the same domain as the XML (http://www.shrewdily.com)?

Comment: The XML is on the same domain, not sure what you mean by url of the map? Here is a snippet of the XML file, but pretty sure nothing is going wrong here:

`<markers>
<marker id="1" name="Loblaws" address="11 Redway Road, East York, ON" lat="43.699417" lng="-79.360100" type="Loblaws"/>
...
</markers>`

Comment: I've also updated the code above for the full page affected. Seems very weird considering there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make two changes to get this to the map to appear with the markers:

1. Remove the 2 excess code lines after the function `initMap()` - those appear to have been copied from the end of the function `downloadUrl()`

   ```
       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
           var center = map.getCenter();
           google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
           map.setCenter(center);
       });
   }
   //Remove these stray lines
   request.open('GET', url, true);
   request.send(null);
   ```
2. Add the CSS styles from the [Google Maps API Markers example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple):

   ```
   <style>
   /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
    * element that contains the map. */
   #map {
       height: 100%;
   }
   /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
   html, body {
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
   }
   </style>
   ```

See the working example [here](http://samonela.scienceontheweb.net/maps/markers.html).